# ansible - Connection timed out during banner exchange when Using jump host

Tags: ansible, bastion-host

The ansible command : `ansible all -m ping -i host.yml`

Here is my host.yml

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    tencent:
      ansible_user: "ubuntu"
      ansible_host: "106.55.XXX.XXX"
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "key.pem"
      ansible_ssh_common_args: 'ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i bastion.key.pem ubuntu@102.106.XXX.XXX"'
```

Error msg:

```
Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection timed out during banner exchange
```

How to correctly use the jump host in ansible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ansible solution:

[How do I configure a jump host to access servers that I have no direct access to?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to)

In my case, just replace the `ansible_ssh_common_args`

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q ubuntu@102.106.XXX.XXX -i ./inventory/bastion.key.pem"'
```